# How to modify testNG DataProvider array objects before test launch (naming tests in Saucelabs)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, dataprovider

I'm running tests in Saucelabs, and need to set a capability at runtime called 'name', which is the name of the test method. This must be done to each DesiredCapabilities object coming from the DataProvider.

Then, I need to instantiate a live RemoteWebDriver object for the test to run with this capability included.

```
@DataProvider(name = "environments")
public static Object[] environments()
{
    EnvironmentParser environmentParser = new EnvironmentParser();
    CapabilitiesFactory capabilitiesFactory = new CapabilitiesFactory(environmentParser);
    return capabilitiesFactory.makeCapabilities("./src/test/resources/webEnvironments.json");
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Method method, DesiredCapabilities[] capabilities) throws MalformedURLException
{
    // Name the test in Saucelabs
    for(int i = 0; i < capabilities.length; i++)
    {
        capabilities[i].setCapability("name", method.getName());
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), capabilities[i]);
    }
}
```

Error when trying to run the code:

Can inject only one of ITestContext, XmlTest, Method, Object[], ITestResult into a @BeforeMethod annotated setUp.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the array must be of type Object[]

The code below works as expected:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Method method, Object[] capabilities) throws MalformedURLException
{
    // Name the test in Saucelabs and create the driver
    for(int i = 0; i < capabilities.length; i++)
    {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = (DesiredCapabilities) capabilities[i];
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("name", method.getName());
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), (DesiredCapabilities) capabilities[i]);
    }
}
```